# Como separar os dados de um arrays em linhas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Peço mais uma ajuda a vocês: Tenho um array bidimensional, e queria separá-lo em linhas em uma coluna, por exemplo:

```
Time 1
Jogador 1
Jogador 2
...

Time 2
Jogador 7
Jogador 8
...
```

Cheguei até o seguinte código:

```js
var array = [["Jogador1","Jogador2","Jogador3","Jogador4","Jogador5","Jogador6"],["Jogador7","Jogador8","Jogador9","Jogador10","Jogador11","Jogador12"]];

$.each(array, function(i,a){
 i++;
  $('body').append('<ul>Time '+i+'</ul><li>'+a+'</li>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Como faria para ajeitar o código? Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teria que fazer 2 laços `$.each`, um para criar as `ul` e outra para as `li`, e não precisa incrementar o `i` com `i++`, basta `i+1`, já economiza 1 linha de código:

```js
var array = [["Jogador1","Jogador2","Jogador3","Jogador4","Jogador5","Jogador6"],["Jogador7","Jogador8","Jogador9","Jogador10","Jogador11","Jogador12"]];

$.each(array, function(i,a){
  $('body').append('<ul><li>Time '+ (i+1) +'</li><ul></ul></ul>')
  
  var ul = $("ul:last"); // seleciona o último ul inserido
  $.each(a, function(i,a){
     ul.append('<li>'+a+'</li>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Lembrando que o conteúdo de um elemento `<ul>` necessita de um `<li>`:
>   `<ul>texto</ul>` é inválido. **Correto:** `<ul><li>texto</li></ul>`

Agora, se você quiser remover as propriedades padrão dos elementos da lista, tem que usar CSS:

```js
var array = [["Jogador1","Jogador2","Jogador3","Jogador4","Jogador5","Jogador6"],["Jogador7","Jogador8","Jogador9","Jogador10","Jogador11","Jogador12"]];

$.each(array, function(i,a){
  $('body').append('<ul class="lista"><li>Time '+ (i+1) +'</li><ul></ul></ul>')
  
  var ul = $("ul:last");
  $.each(a, function(i,a){
     ul.append('<li>'+a+'</li>');
  });
})
```

```css
.lista, .lista li, .lista ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

.lista{
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta completa!! Ajudou e aprendi também!

Comment: Ontem na pressa (e com sono) acabei comentendo alguns erros, mas lendo sua resposta percebi o que errei e atualizei minha resposta. Usar `last` foi um bom "truque", de fato preciso estudar mais jquery...

Answer (score 3):

Você está percorrendo o array com `each`, e a variável `a` representa, a cada iteração, um `array` com os jogadores do time.

Ao jogar todo o array `a` dentro do `li`, você está colocando todos os jogadores no mesmo item da lista.

O correto é percorrer este array `a` e colocar cada jogador em seu próprio `li`. Mudei também o nome da variável `a` para ficar mais claro o que ela é (um array representando um time).

Além disso, o texto "Time x" [deve estar fora do `ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), conforme indicado pela [resposta do @sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/332516/112052). Uma alternativa seria jogá-lo para fora, fazendo com que cada time faça parte de outra `ul` externa.

Ou seja, a estrutura fica assim:

```
<ul>
  <li>Time 1<li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Jogador 1</li>
      <li>Jogador 2</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Time 2<li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Jogador 7</li>
      <li>Jogador 8</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Em jQuery fica assim:

```js
var array = [["Jogador1","Jogador2","Jogador3","Jogador4","Jogador5","Jogador6"],["Jogador7","Jogador8","Jogador9","Jogador10","Jogador11","Jogador12"]];

// criar lista externa (que vai ter todos os times)
$('body').append('<ul id="lista-times" style="list-style: none">');

// para cada time
$.each(array, function(i, time){
    // cria um li com nome do time e outra lista ul para os jogadores
    var idTime = 'time' + (i + 1);
    $('#lista-times').append('<li>Time '+ (i + 1) + '</li><li><ul id="' + idTime + '">');

    // loop para percorrer os jogadores do time
    $.each(time, function(j, jogador) {
        $('#' + idTime).append('<li>' + jogador + '</li>');
    });

    $('#lista-times').append('</ul></li>');
})

$('body').append('</ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Tem também a opção sem jQuery:

```js
var array = [["Jogador1","Jogador2","Jogador3","Jogador4","Jogador5","Jogador6"],["Jogador7","Jogador8","Jogador9","Jogador10","Jogador11","Jogador12"]];

// cria lista externa (que vai ter todos os times)
let ulExt = document.createElement('ul');
ulExt.style.listStyle = 'none';

// para cada time
array.forEach(function(time, i) {
    // cria li com nome do time
    let liTime = document.createElement('li');
    liTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Time '+ (i + 1)));
    ulExt.appendChild(liTime);

    // cria outra lista ul para os jogadores
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    time.forEach( function (jogador, j) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jogador));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    let liJog = document.createElement('li');
    liJog.appendChild(ul);
    ulExt.appendChild(liJog);
});
document.body.appendChild(ulExt);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta!! Também aprendi mais com a sua resposta!!

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio Na pressa acabei cometendo alguns erros, mas agora a estrutura da lista está correta. Atualizei a resposta.